# Problems following Miktex Update (Admin) : copystart.exe and mpm_mfc.exe shortcuts not found

Tags: miktex-update

My PC works withs Windows 10, regularly updated and Miktex 2.9 for years. Today, i've run the Package Udpate manager (As Admin) tha tended normally. Since that operation, I've now a lot of problems. Latex documents can't be compiled successfully with TexMaker due to old or deprecated packages.
I'cannot launch Miktex Settings and Miktex Update. The related window doesnt come and I'va a windows error telling copystart.exe and mpm_mfc.exe are not found.
As I'm not realy a geek, I'ask for assistance to fix my installation after this malicious update.
Regards
Pierre

Comment: Check you path variable. This sounds as if some older system is found.

Comment: The environment variable qhows onlu one item relared ti Miktex, it looks good with : C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\ Is there anaother variable to check?